# R write data.table instruction in functional form/call

Tags: r, data.table

So if I want to get a data.table:DT's customer num sum by category mall_name, I can use:

```
DT[,sum(customer_num),by = mall_name]
```

But in some cases,like I want to apply/lapply this summary to a list of DT, I need the functional form of this compact form: I guess it would be:

```
`[.data.table`(DT,,sum(customer_num),by = mall_name)
```

how ever, this gave me a error:

```
Error: could not find function "[.data.table"
```

Is there anyone know how to write the functional form of it?

Comment: You don't need to use `[.data.table`. Just use `[`. and dispatch to `[.data.table` should happen automatically. You could use `data.table:::\`[.data.table\`` but it's usually not recommended to call internal functions directly.

Comment: In general cases, we use general solution, in special cases, we apply special solution

Comment: sorry, but unless you explain what's so special about your situation, that's just platitudinal nonsense

Comment: When I want to use apply/lapply or when I want to make a complex function including the basic operation in data.table

Comment: You can replace `data.table:::\`[.data.table\`` below with `\`[\``, easily. If you have a situation where that doesn't work, please feel free to edit your question, or to ask a new one :)

Answer (score 2):

As MichaelChirico noted, if you just use

```
`[`(dt, ...)
```

this should automatically use the correct option.

As an alternative, the actual function can be found using:

```
data.table:::`[.data.table`()
```

and used as follows:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(x = 1:5)

listOfDts <- lapply(1:5, function(x)copy(dt))

lapply(listOfDts, function(y) data.table:::`[.data.table`(y, , x := rep(1, 5)))

listOfDts
```

However, be aware of the risks involved using `:::` to access a library's unexported objects. These may change without notice, since they are not exported, and thus not bound to any promised functionality.

An alternative approach to using the functional version of `[` would be:

```
dt <- data.table(x = 1:5)

listOfDts <- lapply(1:5, function(x)copy(dt))

lapply(listOfDts, function(y) y[, x := 1])
```

Comment: `lapply(listOfDts, \`[\`, j = x := 1)` should work as well; YMMV on whether it's more readable

Comment: ah yes, I'm too used to using the anonimous function method